Who is King John played by?
I'm rewatching a show I watched as a child where one of the characters is King John (historical show). The clip I'm watching is a remake and has a different actor playing the King. I've seen this actor before but his name is on the top of my tongue. Unfortunately I'm only watching a clip so it doesn't have any credits. If it helps, the show is called Horrible Histories
This is what he looks like (dressed up):

Any knowledge would be greatly appreciated!

Ben Miller
Of Armstrong and Miller fame.
Credited on the BBC website for his appearance as King John.

Could you elaborate a bit please? What movies/tv shows has he been in?

The link on his name takes you to IMDB, which lists his filmography.

The only thing IMBD does not list are the shows he did with Alexander Armstrong for BBC Radio 4, as they are not a visual medium.
